# Aure Function App returns 'The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized' when using pfx file

Tags: azure, ssl, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function app on a shared app service plan and I don't want to import my certificates through the Azure portal. That is because this app service plan is shared within the organisation and these certificates are client certificates that I want to be sure of that I am the only one able to access them.

So I import them using Function app settings (and I am moving them to the Vault for even more security).

```
byte[] bytearray; // PFX file, imported from settings using base64 encoding
string password; // Imported from settings
certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificates.Import(bytearray, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

Using them goes like this

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
foreach (var cert in certificates)
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

But the connection is refusing with the error 'The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized'.

I tried a few things

- I am sure the PFX is inserted correctly because I can read the 3 certificates that are in them.
- Only one of the certificates has an EKU with Client Authentication, the others are there because this is a privately generated certificate and they represent the chain.
- I tried saving the PFX to local filestorage first. I thought that might be an option because I understand that all certificates go trough the local certificate storage first because of security implications of shielding the private key, and this store keeps a handle open to the PFX file (that might or not exist on disk). That didn't work.
- I know the certificates are OK because I can use them on my Function App when doing this 'the intended way' with uploading on Azure, routing them to the app using WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES, and then in-code selecting them from the store (using the X509Store class).

Comment: Try set appSettings WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1 and see if that helps.

Comment: @SuwatCh Wow, that did the job! In retrospective: it seems as the user profile is not ready (enough) to process certificates in this manner, because of the basic functionality a function app offers by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are setting up `X509Certificate2` instance from a pfx file or cert encoded containing private key, you may run into **CryptographicException**: *The system cannot find the file specified..*

The reason is Windows stores private key as a file under a user profile directory. By default, Azure Web App (AppService) does not load user profile (avoid overhead for majority scenarios where it is not needed). Hence, the The system cannot find the file specified. issue. To work around, set the below appSetting to enable User Profile.

> WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1

By setting the App Setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1`, Azure Websites will load user profiles for the given application, and thus applications can load certificates from PFX files.

References:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/pdf-generation-and-loading-file-based-certificates-in-azure-websites/

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-issue-with-x509certificate2

Comment: Well, this is the info I was looking for and some additional background that explains the 'why'. The referenced articles do not mention the specific error I encountered, but nevertheless they provide additional hooks for better use of certificates in function apps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Not easy to find. Saved my day :)